# Why does WatchService generate so many operations?

Tags: java, nio, java-7, watchservice

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;

public class Tmp {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
        int count = 0;
        Path path = Paths.get("C:\\tmp\\");
        WatchService ws = null;
        try {
            ws = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
            path.register(ws, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE,
                    StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY, StandardWatchEventKinds.OVERFLOW);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        while(true) {
            WatchKey key = null;
            try {
                key = ws.take();
            } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }

            for(WatchEvent<?> event: key.pollEvents()) {
                switch(event.kind().name()) {
                    case "OVERFLOW":
                        System.out.println(++count + ": OVERFLOW");
                        break;
                    case "ENTRY_MODIFY":
                        System.out.println(++count + ": File " + event.context() + " is changed!");
                        break;
                    case "ENTRY_CREATE":
                        System.out.println(++count + ": File " + event.context() + " is created!");
                        break;
                    case "ENTRY_DELETE":
                        System.out.println(++count + ": File " + event.context() + " is deleted!");
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println(++count + ": UNKNOWN EVENT!");
                }
            }

            key.reset();
        }    
    }
}
```

When I run this and then opened the Notepad++ and then created a new empty file and saved it as `a.txt` in the `C:\tmp\` directory I got the output:

```
1: File a.txt is created!
2: File a.txt is deleted!
3: File a.txt is created!
```

Why is that? It looks like the file was created and then deleted and then created again. Why?

When I put some text in the file and saved it the output was:

```
4: File a.txt is changed!
5: File a.txt is changed!
```

Why did it change twice?

Comment: I think the behaviour you're seeing with WatchService is due to the way Notepad++ and to some extend the way the Windows operating system works when performing IO operations. I've found that something like the "standard" Windows notepad usually produces the most expected behaviour. I suspect that if you use Process Explorer (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to monitor the IO activity at an OS level you will see the same results.

Comment: This might be due to the fact that content and metadata writes are performed separately.

Answer (score 2):

Watch Service's Modify event generates two events. When we modify an already existing file, the file system first creates it with 0 bytes and fires a modify event and then writes data on it. Then it fires the modify event again. That's why It was showing two modify events. So What I have done to solve this problem, I just use counter to check my task should be triggered only once on even count

```
        Path path = null;
        int count = 0;

        try {
            path = Paths.get(new Utility().getConfDirPath());
            System.out.println("Path: " + path);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        WatchService watchService = null;
        try {
            watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
            path.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY,StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }


        while(true) {
            WatchKey key = null;
            try {
                key = watchService.take();
            } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }

            for(WatchEvent<?> event: key.pollEvents()) {
                switch(event.kind().name()) {
                    case "ENTRY_MODIFY":
                        System.out.println(++count + ": File " + event.context() + " is changed!");

                        if (count%2==0) {
                            doOnChange(); // do whatever you want
                        }
                        break;
                    case "ENTRY_DELETE":
                        System.out.println(++count + ": File " + event.context() + " is deleted!");
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println(++count + ": UNKNOWN EVENT!");
                }
            }

            // reset the key
            boolean valid = key.reset();
            if (!valid) {
                System.out.println("Key has been unregistered");
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The File creation and deletion events are working correctly in my system(Window 7 + 1.7.0_21).

The change event message is displayed number of time's(n) for each <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> operation on that file.

```
      // Removed the "//" after director name as D://tmp"
      //Added just to see the message with a 1 ms gap.
      Thread.sleep(1000); // after key.reset();
```

Example :
       If we open the file and keep on pressing the crtl + s (save with out any changes/with changes). The following message will display(repeatedly) for each save operation.

```
     File YourFileName.txt is changed!
```

Reason is in windows the WatchService is comparing the file changes with timestamp instead of checksum.

More description given here [Platform dependencies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html)

Comment: That's not a 1ms gap, that's a 1 second gap. Of course you won't see the effect if you wait for a very long time in computer terms before checking again. As for this: "Reason is in windows the WatchService is comparing the file changes with timestamp instead of checksum." uh... what?

Comment: @RobinGreen, Please tell me what's is your exception and your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**this works for me**

```
    // get the first event before looping
    WatchKey key = this.watcher.take();

    // reset key (executed twice but not invoke the polled events)
    while (key != null && key.reset() ) { 
      // polled events
      for (final WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
        System.out.printf("\nGlobal received: %s, event for file: %s\n", event.kind(),
            event.context());

        switch (event.kind().name()) {
        case "ENTRY_CREATE":
          LOGGER.debug("event ENTRY_CREATE");
          break;
        case "ENTRY_DELETE":
          LOGGER.debug("event ENTRY_DELETE");
          break;
        case "ENTRY_MODIFY":
          LOGGER.debug("event ENTRY_MODIFY");
          break;
        default:
          LOGGER.debug("event other [OVERFLOW]");
          break;
        }
      }

      key = this.watcher.take();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a small FileWatcher Utility Library:
https://github.com/finsterwalder/fileutils

It allows to set a grace period. Multiple events inside the grace period are accumulated and only triggered once.

You should not use Notepad++ for your experiments, since you don't know what Notepad++ is doing. It may be, that Notepad++ is actually writing to a file several times. Or it could write a file with a different name and rename it, when done or whatnot.
Write your own code to manipulate files and watch that.